# Parse Json and set row background color depend on a condition

Tags: android

After parsing `Json data` I want when the value of "fork" is `true` to set background color of `getView` method to white and when `false`  to green but it doesn't work.

```
protected void onPostExecute(final String jsonData) {

        super.onPostExecute(jsonData);

         try {
             boolean fork;
            JSONArray data = new JSONArray(jsonData);
            for(int i=0; i<data.length() ;i++) {
                JSONObject GithubObj = data.getJSONObject(i);
                String name = GithubObj.getString("name");
                String description = GithubObj.getString("description");
                JSONObject owner = GithubObj.getJSONObject("owner");
                String userName = owner.getString("login");
                fork = GithubObj.getBoolean("fork");
                String allData = name+ " - "+ description+ " - "+userName;

                if(fork==false){
                  dap = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, GithubList){

                        @Override
                        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                            View v = super.getView(position,convertView,parent);

                                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#90EE90"));
                                dap.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            return v;
                        }
                    };
                }else {
                    dap = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, GithubList){

                        @Override
                        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                            View v = super.getView(position,convertView,parent);

                            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
                            dap.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            return v;
                        }
                    };
                }
                GithubList.add(i, allData);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        listview.setAdapter(dap);
```

Comment: I do not recommend to manipulate view while parsing JSON/XML. This operations should be separated because of code readability. If you mix parsing and view operations than it becomes unmaintainable. I recommend to firstly parse data into your model objects and then manipulate views depending on values that are stored in objects. It would be much easier to find mistakes in code

Comment: I tried that but the problem that once getView return view with specific color it doesn't apply the else statement can u help me more in that because I tried different ways and it doesn't work too.

Comment: MY another suggestion is to move parsing part to separate thread. JSON parsing is time consuming process and doing it in onPostExecute method will block your UI. I would consider setting background color to `convertView` (parameter of function getView).